# jQuery Accordion Menu opens on next page

Tags: jquery

I have a vertically stacked accordion-style menu on the lefthand side of a page. It works, but I don't think it's very intuitive for the user so I would like to improve it.

The HTML is

```
<ul class="leftnav">
  <li><a href="#">South of France</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=South of France">South of France</a></li>
      <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=Provence">Provence</a></li>
      <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=Languedoc">Languedoc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">South-West France</a>
    <ul>
etc
```

and the javascript is

```
  $('.leftnav > li > a').click(function(){
      $(this).next().slideToggle(1200);
  });
```

The user has to click on the "South of France" menu button to open the accordion, and then click again on the second level of menu to get to the desired page. If he is (say) on the "Paris" page, he clicks on "South of France" yet intially finds himself still on the Paris page.

I would like it to work like this:
Click on "South of France" menu button
Accordion opens
South of France page then opens, still with the accordion open

Then if the user wants to narrow the search further he can click Provence or Languedoc.

I have tried various things with document.getElementById('south').click(); etc but nothing has achieved what I am trying to get.

EDIT
I tried to follow Blowski's advice, without success. Seems reasonable, but I'm obviously doing something not right.

I now have this for my HTML

```
<ul class="leftnav">
  <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=South of France">South of France</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=Provence">Provence</a></li>
      <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=Languedoc">Languedoc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">South-West France</a>
    <ul>
etc
```

and this for the javascript

```
  $('.leftnav > li > a').click(function(){
      $(this).next().slideToggle(1200);
      $(this).addClass('open');
  });
  if ($('.leftnav > li > a').attr('class') == 'open'){
      $(this).next().slideDown(1200);
  };
```

SECOND EDIT
The solution offered by EdenSource worked (thanks!) with a little modification.
As the solution relied on the same url parameter existing on the second level of the menu as on the first, I had to include it and then hide it with display:none.

```
<ul class="leftnav">
  <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=South of France">South of France</a>
    <ul>
      <li style="display:none"><a href="tag=South of France"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=Provence">Provence</a></li>
      <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=Provence">Cote d'Azure</a></li>
      <li><a href="/hotels.php?tag=Languedoc">Languedoc</a></li>
    </ul>
etc
```

I also had to reduce the variables in the javascript to just the value of the parameters. I did this with split() and pop().

```
var param = window.location.search.substr(1).split('=');
param = param.pop();
param = param.replace(/%20/g, " ");

$(".leftnav li ul li a").each(function(){
    var getHref = $(this).attr("href").split('=');
    getHref = getHref.pop();
    if(getHref == param){
        $(this).addClass("subActiv");
        $(this).closest("ul").slideDown(1200).closest("li").children().first().addClass("navActiv");    
    }
});
```

The only issue now is that the slideDown is rather jerky, but I know that is a common problem and there are dozens of threads about it. Hopefully one of those will bring me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to identify which sub menu page are we on thanks to `href` attribut:

```
var myUrl = document.location.pathname;

$(document).on("click", ".leftnav > li", function(){
    $("ul", this).slideToggle(500);
});

$(".leftnav li ul li a").each(function(){
    var getHref = $(this).attr("href");

    if(getHref == myUrl){
        $(this).addClass("subActiv");
        $(this).closest("ul").slideToggle(500).closest("li").children().first().addClass("navActiv");    
    }
});
```

> [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nd1usecg/)

In the fiddle, I forced the url to be equal to `"/hotels.php?tag=Languedoc"`

Comment: This worked, with some modification. See my second edit.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the open tab in the accordion, and either set that class on the server side generated code, or do something in JavaScript when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks Blowski. That seems reasonable, but I haven't cracked it yet. See my edit of the original post to see how I have tried to follow your advice.